# Why min-height on firefox is bigger than height?

Tags: html, css, firefox

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/VCyca/) is the code

```
<div style="font-size: 1px; min-height: 1px; background-color: #9DA5E2;">&nbsp;</div>
```

on Firefox it looks bigger then height: 1px (in fact, changing height: 1px with Firebug the div being less height).

In fact, min-height: 1px = height: 3px , that's strange...

Why?

Comment: min-height is a lower bound? so if height >= min-height eversything is fine. Your question is somewhat unclear by the way

Comment: No! I mean, `min-height` displayed is height as `height: 3px`

Comment: ok you use firebug to determine the hight of you div and get `height:3px`? Try setting `height` instead of `min-height`, maybe define the overflow...

Comment: @Ted just try the fiddle. The div with just a `height` is not as high as the div with a `min-height`. Why? "Just use height" is not the answer.

Comment: @MrLister | min height is a lower bound: meaning make it as least 1px height but if you want to make it bigger it is ok. Setting height means make it exactly as high as i tell you too. This implies even though you have to draw the div say 3px high to display its coontents i told you to make it 1 px high so just make it 1px high and cut the content off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you set font-size to 1px but you did not change line-height.

When you set font-size to value x, height of entire line containing text is bigger. More details: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

See also this image for details: http://www.w3.org/Talks/2008/0911-CSS-Amsterdam/line-height.png

Add `line-height:1px;` and it should be okay.

Comment: Why does not setting the line-height cause `min-height` to be larger than `height`?

Comment: Because there should be space between lines of text.Thats why line-height (if not set manually) is always bigger than font size. see: http://www.w3.org/Talks/2008/0911-CSS-Amsterdam/line-height.png